# unit test angular service not able to reach function inside service + jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have written some service in angular.  Check this [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/GdyPlG7mkgKf6SqQSbZj?p=info).

Injecting `CommonService, $rootRouter, ModalService` in `RouteService`.

I am stuck with unit testing these services. You can see sample spec file at [PLUNKER](http://PLUNKER).

**EDIT: Whatever test I have at plunker are not working as expected. Am not sure what I am doing wrong.**

How to test `goTo` and `getActivePage` methods in `RouteService`?

How to test `getProperty` and `setProperty` methods in `CommonService`?

Here is code.

First service is **RouteService**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mysampleapp')
.service('RouteService',
  function(CommonService, $rootRouter, ModalService) {

    console.log('RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRoute');

    return {
      goTo: goTo,
      getActivePage: getActivePage
    };

    function goTo(page) {
      var valid = CommonService.getProperty('isValidationSuccess');

      switch (page) {
        case 'AboutUs':
          if (valid) {
            CommonService.setProperty('activeMenu', page);
            $rootRouter.navigate([page]);
          } else {
            ModalService.openModal('Analysis Error', 'Complete Application Group configuration prior to running analysis.', 'Error');
          }
          break;

        default:
          CommonService.setProperty('activeMenu', page);
          $rootRouter.navigate([page]);
          break;
      }
    }

    function getActivePage() {
      return CommonService.getProperty('activeMenu');
    }

  });
```

Another is **CommonService**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mysampleapp')
.service('CommonService',
  function() {

    var obj = {
      /* All page validation check before perform analysis */
      isValidationSuccess: false,
      /* Highlight the menu */
      activeMenu: 'HomeMenu'
    };


    function setProperty(key, value) {

      obj[key] = value;
    }

    function getProperty(key) {
      return obj[key];
    }

    function getAllProperties() {
      return obj;
    }

    return {
      setProperty: setProperty,
      getProperty: getProperty,
      getAllProperties: getAllProperties
    };
  }
);
```

Comment: hey, I posted my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40079280/2545680) for `CommonService` test. Please create a separate question for `RouteService`.

Comment: see the que here with real scenario of my application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084091/unit-testing-two-service-which-are-in-different-module-with-jasmine

Comment: @Maximus u got any chance to look on new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084091/unit-testing-two-service-which-are-in-different-module-with-jasmine

Comment: I'll take a look tomorrow, it's late in here today)

Comment: do you still need help? It seems that rossoneri have given correct answer

Comment: Let me check wil update

Answer (score 2):

In your plunker you forgot to create the `mysampleapp` module before adding services to it:

```
angular.module('mysampleapp', []);
```

The test for setters and getters of `CommonService` should be pretty simple:

```
describe('CommonService', function () {
    var commonService;

    beforeEach(module('mysampleapp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_CommonService_) {
        commonService = _CommonService_;
    }));

    it('should set and get property', function () {
        commonService.setProperty('isValidationSuccess', 'Perform');
        expect(commonService.getProperty('isValidationSuccess')).toBe('Perform');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Unit tests for services in most cases should be islolated from other services. If you going to testing `CommonService` you must mock other services, such as `CommonService` and etc. Main reason that you do not have to worry how to run for another service, because in this test you expecting that other services will work correctly.

```
describe('RouteService', function () {
'use strict';

var RouteService,
    ModalService,
    CommonService,
    mockedValue,
    $rootRouter;

beforeEach(module('mysampleapp'));

beforeEach(inject(function (_RouteService_, _ModalService_, _CommonService_, _$rootRouter_) {
    RouteService = _RouteService_;
    ModalService = _ModalService_;
    CommonService = _CommonService_;
    $rootRouter = _$rootRouter_;

    $rootRouter.navigate = jasmine.createSpy();

    ModalService.openModal = jasmine.createSpy(); //sometimes open modal return promise, and you should check it to

    CommonService.getProperty = jasmine.createSpy().and.callFake(function () {
        return mockedValue;
    });

    CommonService.setProperty = jasmine.createSpy().and.callFake(function () {
        return mockedValue;
    });

}));

it('should exist', function () {
    expect(RouteService).toBeDefined();
});

it('should get active page', function () {
    RouteService.getActivePage();

    expect(CommonService.getProperty).toHaveBeenCalled(); //this test make sens only for make you coverage 100%, in you case i mean
});

describe('goTo method', function () {
    it('should check if it is valid page', function () {
        RouteService.goTo();

        expect(CommonService.getProperty).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('should set property if page is "about as" and if it is valid page, and should navigate to this page', function () {
        mockedValue = true;

        var page = 'AboutUs';

        RouteService.goTo(page);

        expect(CommonService.setProperty).toHaveBeenCalledWith('activeMenu', page);
        expect($rootRouter.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith([page]);

        expect(ModalService.openModal).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('should open modal with error if "about as" is not valid page', function () {
        var isValid = mockedValue = false;

        var page = 'AboutUs';

        RouteService.goTo(page);

        expect(ModalService.openModal).toHaveBeenCalled();

        expect(CommonService.setProperty).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect($rootRouter.navigate).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('should set property and navigate to page', function () {
        var page = 'Test Page';

        RouteService.goTo(page);

        expect(CommonService.setProperty).toHaveBeenCalledWith('activeMenu', page);
        expect($rootRouter.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith([page]);

        expect(ModalService.openModal).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for detailed answers. but somehow it's getting broke. all test are failing with same error i.e. 1. Expected undefined to be defined.
2. TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RouteService.getActivePage')

Comment: What could be the root cause for `Expected undefined to be defined.` any leads will be appreciate? Is that bcoz mine `CommonService` is in different module. I also tried to change `CommonService` module same as `RouteService` module, still it didn't worked.

Comment: @ankitd, sory i am busy, i will prepare example late.

Comment: it's okay :) will wait for your response.

Comment: @ankitd I made a few mistakes, this tests working for me. If you are using separate modules it is should also working. Example: `angular.module("parent", ["child"])`.

Comment: @ankitd i have updated the tests, just want you know, try to use and let me know if it working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125979/discussion-between-ankitd-and-rossoneri).