# unit testing two service which are in different module with jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have written some service in angular.  Check this [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/KSbnhfLONA9Rg3zxH7on?p=info).

Injecting `CommonService, $rootRouter, ModalService` in `RouteService`.

Mind the module :

- `CommonService` is in `mysampleapp.core`
- `RouteService` is in `mysampleapp`

Also when I try to do this

```
beforeEach(module('mysampleapp.core'));
beforeEach(module('mysampleapp'));
```

It gives me some weird `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Map (line 2166)` error. Do i need to do the above or am doing it in wrong way??

I am stuck with unit testing RouteService. You can see sample spec file at [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/KSbnhfLONA9Rg3zxH7on?p=info).

How to test `goTo` and `getActivePage` methods in `RouteService`?

Here is code.

First service is **RouteService**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mysampleapp.core')
.service('RouteService',
  function(CommonService, $rootRouter, ModalService) {

    console.log('RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRoute');

    return {
      goTo: goTo,
      getActivePage: getActivePage
    };

    function goTo(page) {
      var valid = CommonService.getProperty('isValidationSuccess');

      switch (page) {
        case 'AboutUs':
          if (valid) {
            CommonService.setProperty('activeMenu', page);
            $rootRouter.navigate([page]);
          } else {
            ModalService.openModal('Analysis Error', 'Complete Application Group configuration prior to running analysis.', 'Error');
          }
          break;

        default:
          CommonService.setProperty('activeMenu', page);
          $rootRouter.navigate([page]);
          break;
      }
    }

    function getActivePage() {
      return CommonService.getProperty('activeMenu');
    }

  });
```

Comment: `ReferenceError` is mostly useless without call stack. It isn't clear where the error takes place. Any way, it likely refers to `Map` ES6 global https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map which should be polyfilled.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since you're trying to test `RouteService`, you just need to inject the module it is in, i.e. `mysampleapp.core`. So that's what I'll be doing here. So this should be you test case for `RouteService`:

```
   /**
     * This code is copyright (c) 2016 DELLEMC Corporation
     */
    'use strict';

    describe('RouteService', function() {

        var RouteService, ModalService, CommonService;
        // You don't need these. So commenting these out.
        //     mockedValue, commonServiceSpy, RouteServiceSpy;

        beforeEach(module('mysampleapp.core'));

        // Wasn't sure what these are, so commented these out.
        // beforeEach(module('basic-unity-replication-sizer-ui.core'));
        // beforeEach(module('basic-unity-replication-sizer-ui'));

        beforeEach(inject(function(_RouteService_, _ModalService_, _CommonService_, $rootRouter) {
            RouteService = _RouteService_;
            ModalService = _ModalService_;
            CommonService = _CommonService_;
            $rootRouter.navigate = jasmine.createSpy();
        }));

        // This should pass.
        it('should exist', function() {
            expect(RouteService).toBeDefined();
            expect(angular.isFunction(RouteService.goTo)).toBeTruthy();
            expect(angular.isFunction(RouteService.getActivePage)).toBeTruthy();
        });
    });
```

Also since there wasn't a specified definition of `mysampleapp.core`, I took the liberty to define it. I specified `mysampleapp` and `ngComponentRouter` as dependencies. This is how:

```
angular.module('mysampleapp.core', ['mysampleapp', 'ngComponentRouter']).service('RouteService', function(CommonService, $rootRouter, ModalService) {
        return {
            goTo: goTo,
            getActivePage: getActivePage
        };

        function goTo(page) {
            var valid = CommonService.getProperty('isValidationSuccess');

            switch (page) {
                case 'AboutUs':
                    if (valid) {
                        CommonService.setProperty('activeMenu', page);
                        $rootRouter.navigate([page]);
                    } else {
                        ModalService.openModal('Analysis Error', 'Complete Application Group configuration prior to running analysis.', 'Error');
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    CommonService.setProperty('activeMenu', page);
                    $rootRouter.navigate([page]);
                    break;
            }
        }

        function getActivePage() {
            return CommonService.getProperty('activeMenu');
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Throws Error As: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Map

Comment: @Mithun, your code must be different and you would have forgotten to declare some variables.

Comment: The same code even i am relying on. Its not working for me... :(